# Wrong xpath for nav html tag

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I m trying to find element using xpath for tag

```
<nav id="nav">... </nav>
```

this works:

```
WebElement navigationPane = firefox.findElement(By.className("nav"));
```

but this does not:

```
WebElement navigationPane = 
            firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='nav')]"));
```

How do I make it valid expression in xpath?

Comment: is this a typo? the first statement uses `class` while the second `id`

Comment: you can also use `//*[@id='nav']`

Answer (score 1):

In the xpath expression, you've meant to use `@class` instead of `@id`. And, there is an extra parenthesis inside. Here is the fixed version:

```
//nav[@class = 'nav']
```

---

After finding an HTML block in your question (made it visible with an edit), I've realized that there is an `id` attribute set on the element, not `class`. In this case, you should use the following expression:

```
//nav[@id = 'nav']
```

Note that `by.id` would be an easier and faster way to find the element:

```
WebElement navigationPane = firefox.findElement(By.id("nav"));
```

Comment: I dont' know honestly,

Comment: no in the first i used to find by classname - I know this works, but I want to learn to select elements by xpath